# How to set date format for the result of a SELECT statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I know how to use CONVERT function in SELECT statement to change the format of the Date column:

```
   SELECT 
       StationID
       , CONVERT(varchar, [Date], 101) as Date
       , Value 
   FROM my_table
```

But I was wondering if I can set the date format in general before running the SELECT statement, when I don't know the name of the date column in the following SELECT statement:

```
   SELECT * from FROM my_table
```

Is any SET statement or other T-SQL that I can run before my SELECT statement so that I can change the Date format temporarily?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you writing code where you don't know the names of your columns? Please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx

Comment: The reason is the SQL statement generates dynamically when user selects an option. If I want to have the identify the column name, I have to set a big list of "if" statement to find which option the user selects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

In particular, any date columns which you select are not actually formatted at all, but are instead returned down the wire as an actual piece of date data in a binary "format" which is used for dates.  If you are seeing them formatted, it's because your client (either management studio or some other tool) is converting them to strings to display.

When you use `SELECT *`, there is obviously no way to tell SQL Server to do any conversions on any particular columns, so the data is going to be returned in whatever the data types of the underlying query returns.  So regardless of whether your data types are really date or not, no manipulation is going to happen at that point anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to do what you're asking. However, there are ways to format the date string when you output it using your programming language.